# AngularJS UI-Router navigate to a child URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Trying to link to a child URL using Angular UI-Router (very new to this)

I have:-

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/products")

  $stateProvider
    .state('products', {
        url: "/products",
        templateUrl: "products.html",
    })
    .state('products.edit', {
        url: "/:id",
        templateUrl: "products.edit.html",
        controller: function ($scope, $stateParams) {
          $scope.id = $stateParams.id;
          console.log($stateParams.id)
        }
    })    
    .state('customers', {
        url: "/customers",
        templateUrl: "customers.html",
    });     
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);         
});
```

I can navigate to products and customers, but not the products.edit state.

Here is a [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fa1fBb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `products.edit` is the child state of `products`, the view of the former is to be embedded into the view of the latter.  So in `products.html`, you need to include a `<ui-view>` where `ui-router` will place the child view.  Like this:

```
<div>
 <h4>Products Page</h4>
 <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

See this [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CK1KkI?p=preview).

Comment: aaah ... perfect! Makes sense now.